# Bixby Studio Simulator doesn't show me rendered views

Tags: bixby

I was expecting that the Bixby Simulator would show me the rendered view, but it only shows me the dialog I have given and any converstation-driver.

I am using the current Bixby Studio (version 6.8.2-r19g.7538) on Windows 10 Pro 64 bit and I am having a de-DE capsule.

My result-view looks like this - the respective action of type Search is triggered:

```
result-view {
    match: _ (this)

    render {
        layout {
            section {
                content {
                    single-line {
                        text {
                            value {
                                template ("abc")
                            }
                            style (Title_M)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

The Debugger shows me the following:

```
Evaluate render block
    resources/base/views/Test.view.bxb
        [section]
            [single-line]
                [text]
                    value abc
                    style Title_M
    Rendered layout template
```

[image]

Comment: #1 the result-view you posted works fine.

Comment: #2 However, the `match: _ (this)` would be the default if there is no other match, and if you have two _ match, only a (random) one will be displayed. You also mentioned something about conversation drivers, but conversation drivers should be in the result-view file. Do you have other view files in your capsule?

Comment: Please file an issue through the IDE, using "Contact Support". It should be in the Help menu.

Comment: Yeah, in this tiny example I left out the conversation driver. Nevertheless also the update to 6.9.x didn't fix it. So I filed now an issue at the support.

Comment: Apologies if this should be a comment, but my account is new and my rep is too low to comment. I ran into the same issue on Windows 10 running the sample capsule bixby-views: https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-samples-collection/tree/master/bixby-views I ran the same capsule on macOS Mojave with no issues. Looks like a windows issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reaching out the Samsung Bixby Dev Team the problem is that my Windows user name included spaces, e.g. "User name", and therefore my Windows user folder contained spaces as well, e.g. "C:\Users\User name\". That was a problem, so if you get rid of any spaces in your user folder path, e.g. "C:\Users\Username\" then it fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for submitting the capsule.

After exam the capsule **tinytest**, I think the problem is your JS file returning an empty string. Try return some non-empty string, it will render.

Please also note that you are correct that the view model did **NOT** render/trigger at all due to the empty string returned in JS file. That is the reason in your early code that "abc" is not rendered.

Unless you expect an empty string as a valid output value, I would recommend test with non-empty string.

You can download [dice capsule](https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-sample-dice) to make sure your PC & windows environment is compatible.

Have fun with Bixby!

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It doesn't even work with a valid string returned in the JS file. The support team is already having a look into it. I will post the answer here once the issue is resolved.

Comment: (FYI: He is the support team.)

Comment: The **tinytest** capsule you submitted will work and render. Attached screenshot is taken after I changed JS file to `return "not empty";`

Comment: It still doesn't render on my pc, so I think the Bixby Studio Simulator breaks at any point in the background on my PC setup. It doesn't break compiler-wise. The debug console shows that it should have rendered it, but the Simulator doesn't show me the Single Line. Maybe the software is having an issue with something graphically missing (Windows library etc.)?

Comment: You can download the dice capsule, and test the utterance. If does not render, then it might be a window or setup issue. I've add the link to the answer

Comment: I am sorry to tell, but unfortunately it didn't work either. Nevertheless, thank you for your help. I think my PC lacks a library that the Bixby Studio requires/needs, but I don't know which. I already updated VC++.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest using the contact support option in Bixby IDE, make sure you send screen shot from dice capsule where the title message print but not the content, and a screen shot with your PC's configuration (Windows version, etc)